# PostgreSQL: What is the maximum column length for CITEXT type

Tags: oracle11g, postgresql-9.1

I am migrating my PostgreSQL9.1 schema to Oracle11g. I could not find online what is the maximum column length for CITEXT type column. What size should I put for Oracle when using VARCHAR2 type.

**Note:** I know CITEXT provides case-insensitive comparison, but, I am not much concerned with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [citext](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/citext.html) documentation `citext` is just a case insensitive version of `text`. `text` itself is of unlimited length (well, 1G actually). Therefore you cannot assume any meaningful upper limit. You have to ask the app developers for practical limits of each column.

Comment: I read through this documentation, however, I missed the statement `Otherwise, it behaves almost exactly like text.`.